# Queue calls strategy

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I am using rrmemory as strategy in Q1 and Q2. 
queue members are Local/3001@agent, Local/3002@agent, Local/3003@agent and Local/3004@agent.
Local/3001@agent and Local/3002@agent penalty 0 in Q1 and Local/3003@agent and Local/3004@agent penalty 5 in Q1
Local/3001@agent and Local/3002@agent penalty 5 in Q2 and Local/3003@agent and Local/3004@agent penalty 0 in Q2
now the requirement is if penalty 0 agents are busy (on the call) don’t send a new call to them and send a new call to penalty 5 agents.
if penalty 5 agents are also busy (on the call) then send a new call to penalty 0 agents even though penalty 0 agents are already on the call (busy).

I have limited 1 call to an agent at a time.
I need to send a new call to agents who are already on the call.

Comment: Sorry, not clear what is your question.

Comment: main objective is send 1 call to each the agent at a time.
but if all agents are busy then send new calls to busy agents.

Comment: It is questions site, not "objective". If you want someone do your work instead of you, use upwork. If you want answer, you should ask question more correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do it cleanly. If call limit is set to 1, no new calls will reach that agent if he is busy, and if it is not set, new calls will upset him all the time.

So, is it impossible? Well, you can do it if every agent has 2 SIP accounts. For example, agent1 has Local/3001@agent and you create an extra account for him (Local/4001@agent). This new account has a penalty of 6. That way, only when all agents are in call "extra agents" will be called. It is not clean but if you use Linphone or some softphone that allows you to register 2 account in one device, it will be possible.

Anyway, and in my opinion, it is not a good idea to send 2 calls to one agent. If you want then to be notified that all agents are in call, I would use other method (e-mail, Push notifications to their browser, etc.).

Hope I have helped :)

Comment: Call limit not always shared between queues. ringinuse=no and ringinuse = yes in two queues can work with same agents.